# how to extract multiple edittexts values and multiply values in it

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app where i need to extract values from 2 edittexts 'a', 'b' and multiply it and send result to another edittext 'c'. Can it be possible ? Please,help i am new to android. Advance thanks.

I have tried as below:

```
    iname=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText2);  
    iname.setText(inventorylistitems.getInventoryname());
    iname.setEnabled(false);
    icost=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    icost.setText(String.valueOf(inventorylistitems.getCost()));

    eb=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    amt=(EditText)v.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    eb.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){

       @Override
       public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)){
                int quan=Integer.parseInt(eb.getText().toString());

            int amount=Integer.parseInt(amt.getText().toString());
            int cbf=quan*amount;
            amt.setText(String.valueOf(cbf));
            icost.setEnabled(false);
            amt.setEnabled(false);
        }
   });
```

Comment: what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: app crashes and throws an error numberformat exception invalid int" "

Comment: Whats the problem in your code???

Comment: i dont know where is problem in code.......

Comment: its not showing any line or where its invalid int

Comment: You need to wrap your `parse` statements in a `try/catch` and display a message to the user or take some action if the `EditText` contains a non-int

Comment: @codeMagic-how to do that i am new to java as well as android?

Comment: @codeMagic-where u posted example?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to to do is this:

```
int one = Integer.parseInt(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString());
int two = Integer.parseInt(((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2)).getText().toString());
int three = one * two;
((EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3)).setText(String.valueOf(three));//avoid ResourceNotFoundException
```

Comment: ((EditText)findviewById(R.id.editText3)).setText(three); this row will  cause a ResourceNotFoundException.

Comment: setText is overloaded to take a int paramtert, which will look up for a String with the int you provided as paramter

Comment: cool, just saw. i am used to setText("some string") hence i thought giving a number would be just as same. thank you @blackbelt.

Answer (score 0):

```
try
{
     int amount=Integer.parseInt(amt.getText().toString());
}
catch (NumberFormatException e)
{
   Toast.makeText(YourClass.this, "You have entered invalid numbers", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

You can wrap all of the code in the `onKey()` in the`try/catch` but this will `catch` the exception if an invalid number was entered and display the message shown. You also could display a dialog if you wanted or say display an error message in the `EditText`, log it, whatever you want to do